# Where are the time and date pickers in Android Studio 3.1.1?

Tags: android-studio, datepicker

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.1 and now I can't find the time nor the date pickers.

I'm running on a Linux machine, and the upgrade was suggested by Android Studio and I just clicked OK.
Below is a screenshot of my palette:

[image]

Any idea where I can find them? I'm looking for these two guys:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for is DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog.
You can add it programmatically. In this example onclick edittext event. 
For DatePickerDialog :

```
    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //set date format
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            YourDateEditText.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }

    };

    YourDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

For TimePickerDialog :

```
YourTimeEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    YourTimeEditText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Bona, thanks for your post. I had seen the ones you mention: they are text fields that filter numbers so they match an hour or a date. I'm searching for the pickers, I added a picture to my question above to make clear what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bona, thanks again. My next step would have been to actually use the pickers, so you saved me a search :-). I can add the pickers programmatically now, but I would still have expected them to be available on the palette. Or is something wrong why my installation?

Comment: BTW, I would suggest that you put put your original answer (the xml declarations) on top of the new one. That way, someone else searching would find the complete story in one place.